# C# Timer - Run code whilst timer running

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I'm new to C# and I'm trying to create a simple brain training program using Windows Forms that I learnt when learning Android App development. I'm stuck on the Timer. I have it working and it triggers every second and updates the label on my form. When I add code after I have started the timer, the timer stops. It's like I doesn't run in the background. I've read lots about threading timers and from timers etc, but I've not managed to get anything to work. Like I said, I'm new to C# so please be gentle.... He's my code....

```
public partial class BrainTrainer : Form
{
    // Set global timer variables & Create Timer
    static int secondCounter = 10;
    static bool play = false;
    static Timer myTimer = new Timer();


    public BrainTrainer()
    {
        // Set up form
        InitializeComponent();
        toggleLabels(false);
        timerLbl.Text = secondCounter.ToString() + "s";


    }

    // Function to loop through labels and disabled them
    private void toggleLabels(bool state)
    {
        var ansLabels = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
            .Where(c => c.Name.StartsWith("ans"))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var label in ansLabels)
        {

            label.Enabled = state;
        }
    }

    // Event to run every second
    private void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (secondCounter == 0)
        {
            //Stop Game
            myTimer.Stop();
            play = false;

        }
        else
        {
            // Countdown 1 and update label
            secondCounter--;
            timerLbl.Text = secondCounter.ToString()+"s";
        }
    }

    private void startBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Hide button, set play to true and enable labels
        startBtn.Hide();
        play = true;
        toggleLabels(true);

        // Set up timer event, interval and start
        myTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
        myTimer.Interval = 1000;
        myTimer.Start();
        // Run function to play
        genEquation();    

    }

    private void genEquation()
    {
        while (play)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(secondCounter);   
        }

    }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciate, or a link to a helpful tutorial would be great!

Comment: If you want to alter any UI elements from a timer callback, use the DispatcherTimer class.

Comment: a timer is like a metronome on the tick it does something but thats it util the next tick it doesnt do anything. So for example, a timer set to 15 seconds and on ticket to show date/time on a label will update every 15 seconds.. nothing else happens

Comment: You are adding event subscription every time the button is clicked, which can cause serious bugs

Comment: @Clemens, can you point in the correct direction of the dispatch timer as when I tried this I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: @BugFinder, thanks, I get that. But the tick stops "ticking" when I run code after I start the timer.

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, how would I do this. I tried putting the `.tick` and `.interval` outside of the function, where I initialised the timer, but it wouldn't accept it.

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow, sorted it. Put in in the main method.

Comment: Hard to tell, but does this run correctly the first time you do this? Or does it not work at all?

Comment: You do know that it's not `WPF` and it is in fact `Winforms` that you are using

Comment: Just a guess: You are blocking the current Thread and dont give it time to process the .Tick-Event. The Winforms-Timer does not start a thread for it. Try calling Application.DoEvents() in your genEquation() loop to porcess the event.

Comment: No, won't run at all. If I don't include `genEquation()`. Everything works fine, my timer runs and counts down, updates the label etc. As soon as I try and run `genEquation()`, which is a loop the timer stops. If I remove the loop and just get that function to display a message box it works. Is it something to do with threading? If so how do I get around this, have zero knowledge of this!

Comment: @Hyarus, that's it. Working now! Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks @Franck, did say I was a complete c# noob ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Problem was solved in the Comments*

You are blocking the current Thread and dont give it time to process the .Tick-Event. The Winforms-Timer does not start a thread for it. Try calling Application.DoEvents() in your genEquation() loop to porcess the event.

```
private void genEquation()
{
    while (play)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();   
        Console.WriteLine(secondCounter);
    }    
}
```